# Querying on Date in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah

I'm inserting a Mongo doc with the following time-stamp:

```
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
format.format(new Date()).toLong
```

Here's what the section looks like from Mongo's shell:

`"{Timestamp" : NumberLong("20130919161948")}"`

Based on a few tests, it appears to me that I can simply compare 2 documents by Timestamp by simply checking `>` or `<` for the `yyyyMMddHHmmss` format.

Please let me know if this time-stamp is OK for Mongo. Will I be able to query with it?

Comment: why not to use bson date for timestamp and compare them as dates?

Answer (score 2):

Mongo will not understand this as a timestamp, but as a number. As you set your date with a format going from year to seconds, you will be able to query mongo using > or < to know if it is before or after.

However if you want to mongo to treat the data as a date, you will need to use the appropriate [bson](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) date format. By having mongo treat it as a date, you will have all Mongo date operations available, like extracting year, day of week, etc.. [read more](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operator-date/)

If you are using casbah, and Joda, you can enable serialization and deserialization by an explicit call:

```
import com.mongodb.casbah.conversions.scala._
RegisterJodaTimeConversionHelpers()
```

Read more [here](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.0/tutorial.html).

Comment: Looks like there's no `Scala` API (http://bsonspec.org/#/implementation), but there's a `Java` one. So I need to find the right type, and then insert that to Mongo?

Answer (score 0):

@Kevin, I think you are right. `java.util.Date` is [supported](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java-types/#dates-times) in BSON object.

Using NumberLong to represent timestamp allows you to do range queries, but with BSON [date type](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date), [date operation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/operators/#date-operators) in aggregation framework becomes possible, which is more powerful.

Comment: No need to use java. There is a scala one in casbah.